# How to make two function parameters as implicit

Tags: scala

Assume we have Object that takes function as parameter of `apply` method:

```
object Wrapper {
  def apply(block: TypeA => String) = {
    TypeA a = ...
    block(a)
  }
}
```

`TypeA` is domain type of application.

Now when I define inline block I can define `TypeA` parameter as implicit:

```
Wrapper { implicit a => functionThatUseImplicitA() }
```

But what if `block` parameter is not `Function1`, but `Function2`? How can I define both parameters as implicit?

```
object Wrapper2 {
  def apply(block: (TypeA, TypeB) => String) = {
    TypeA a = ...
    TypeB b = ...
    block(a, b)
  }
}
```

This one does not work:

```
Wrapper { implicit (a, b) => functionThatUseImplicitAB() }
```

The only workaround is define them as vals:

```
Wrapper { (a, b) => 
  implicit val ia = a
  implicit val ib = b
  functionThatUseImplicitAB()
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [SLS](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) **6.23
Anonymous Functions** `implicit` keyword is allowed only for single argument functions:

```
Expr ::= (Bindings | [‘ implicit ’] id | ‘_’) ‘=>’ Expr
ResultExpr ::= (Bindings | ([‘ implicit ’] id | ‘_’) ‘:’ CompoundType) ‘=>’ Block
```

So you can't make two function parameters as implicit.

This is the one of reasons to use curried functions:

```
object Wrapper {
  def apply(block: TypeA => TypeB => String) = ???
}

Wrapper { implicit a => implicit b =>
  functionThatUseImplicitAB()
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how to solve this issue with curried functions? functionThatUseImplicit* are from external API

Comment: @AlexeyRomantchouk: I've updated my answer. It solves your problem when you can change definition of `Wrapper`.