# Custom Actions with multiple implicit arguments

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1, slick

Our Play application uses Slick as a data access layer. This means that in almost every action in our app we need to have both the current `Request` and Slick's database `Session` implicitly available on the scope.

I want to write a custom `Action` to do this so we only need one line to do this. What I want to do is write it in such a way that I can write something like this:

```
def someAction = DBAction { implicit request, session =>
  // body with implicit request and session on scope
```

But this is not valid syntax. Using a tuple does not work because it cannot implicitly unpack the tuple in action body. Is it possible to create a custom action that passes multiple implicit arguments to the body? How do I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make two function parameters as implicit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17296436/how-to-make-two-function-parameters-as-implicit)

Comment: There are two ways to achieve that: a curryed action (`Request[AnyContent] => Session => Result` -> See the @DCKing answer below), or a WrappedRequest (see my answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot implicit 2 variables like that.

But your Custom action can return a `WrappedRequest` (an object which encapsulates the request and your session), and you can define an implicit conversion between this wrapped request and  your Session.

Try this example, derived from this [class](https://github.com/Xamplez/Xamplez/blob/master/app/services/auth/OAuth2Authentication.scala).

```
sealed case class DBRequest(session: Session, private val request: Request[AnyContent])
  extends WrappedRequest(request)

trait DBController extends Controller {

  // Implicit conversion from DBRequest to Session
  implicit def session(implicit request: DBRequest) = request.session

  def DBAction(action: DBRequest => Result) = Action { request =>
    database.withSession { session =>
      action(DBRequest(session, request))
    }
  }
}

object MyController extends Controller with DBController {

  def myAction = DBAction { implicit request =>
    println(session)
  }
}
```

Comment: Great suggestion! I prefer the curried solution better because the code is simpler and doesn't require implicit conversion magic :)

Comment: I like this version because it avoids multiple `w => x => y => z`. But your solution works great for "2 levels" Actions!

Answer (score 2):

@senia was right, currying needs to be used to do this. This is actually addressed in the [Play docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ScalaActionsComposition) but it's a recent addition I missed.

For future reference for people looking for this, my custom action now looks like this:

```
def DBAction(action: Request[AnyContent] => Session => Result) = {
  Action { request =>
    database.withSession { session =>
       action(request)(session)
    }
  }
}
```

Which I can then use in the following way:

```
def someAction = DBAction { implicit request => implicit session => /* body */ }
```