# Scala syntax with two right hand operator in a function

Tags: scala, playframework

Can anyone please help me to understand below scala syntax?

```
def index = withAuth {
  implicit request => userId =>
    Ok(views.html.app.index())
}
```

Syntax taken from [here](https://github.com/gigiigig/play-akka-angular-websocket/blob/master/app/controllers/AppController.scala).

My understanding is: `withAuth` is an `Action` and request is an input to anonymous function. 
However I can't understand

1. Two right hand operators (`=>`)
2. From where it will receive `userId` value?
3. Is `userId` also an input parameter to anonymous function?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a just an anonymous [curried](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) function. Function with single argument that returns function with single argument.

```
// anonymous function that returns function:
implicit request => {
  val inner = userId: UserIdType => Ok(views.html.app.index())
  inner
}

// inline `inner` and use type inference for UserIdType:
implicit request => {
  userId => Ok(views.html.app.index())
}


// remove curly brackets for single expression result:
implicit request =>
  userId => Ok(views.html.app.index())
```

One can call such function this way:

```
curriedFunction(a)(b)
```

Type of `withAuth` parameter is like this `RequestType => UserIdType => ResultType`. It allows you to make request as `implicit`. [See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17296677/406435)

Comment: Thanks for detail lovely explanation :).Syntax to call the function helped me to understand more.